# Cannot find image digest in <region>.artifacts.<project-id>.appspot.com

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-container-registry

I have uploaded a docker image to Google container Registry via docker push command. This push was successful and I am able to view the image in gcr. But when I check this image's digest in the default storage bucket '.artifacts..appspot.com' I do not find that image there. Am I missing on something ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not all parts of the image are stored in GCS buckets. And you probably should not rely on the fact that it is in GCS (except where clearly stated in the docs - e.g. permissions).

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you missed anything but I did find this article[1] which explains that as of February 28th, 2017 the image metadata including the digest is not stored in the same bucket as your project. However, the image layer files should still be stored there.

If you are not seeing the images then there is a possibility that there is a UI issue or that you’re having permission [2] problems.

[1] - https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/support/deprecation-notices#container_image_metadata_storage_change

[2] - https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control

Comment: I have verified the permissions are valid.

Comment: If you have all permissions in check (including Storage Admin) then you may need to contact GCP support so that they can investigate further considering your push was successful.

Comment: Found each image layer in the bucket. So basically each layer wise digest mapping is present. Thanks @Vivak P